# Perl Archive::Rar handle archives with password?

Tags: perl, extract, archive, rar

Looking for a way to unrar archives with a password!
I´m using this for the ones with no pass:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Archive::Rar;

$archive = "test.rar";

$unrar = Archive::Rar->new(archive => "$archive");
$unrar->Extract ();
```

The password for this would be 'pass123'.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`Archive::Rar` is thin, yet convoluted wrapper around real binary, providing very narrow control of process, while having tons of meaningless data moving around inside it. Please consider just manually calling `rar` binary through Perl's many IPC facilities instead or using `Archive::Unrar` if you're on Windows platform.

Anyway, because this module have pretty sloppy data control, and if you only want quick and dirty script for *one shot task*, you can fool it to put anything you want in command line through injecting flags in file list:

```
my $unrar = Archive::Rar->new(archive => $archive);
$unrar->{args}{-files} = ['.', '-ppass123'];
$unrar->Extract;
```